# How GUI implemented from video card to Qt framework?

Tags: qt, user-interface, x11

I've been curious about how GUIs are implemented for a long time. I know how to write Qt (or other) code, and I want to know:

- How Qt calls Xlib (under Linux), and implements the Qt framework.
- How Xlib calls linux system calls
- How Linux controls the video card

Are there any good articles for introducing GUI implementations?

Comment: You want us to write an article on GUI implementation for you?

Comment: No, I want resource about it, and write it myself.

Comment: I'm not going to google this for you...

Answer (score 1):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System#Design